# How to copy Luma Layered Navigation to Blank Theme

Tags: magento2.3, layered-navigation, luma-theme, blank-theme

I have created a custom theme in **Magento 2.3** which is extended from the blank theme.

I would like to use the luma layered navigation.

I have copied `Magento_LayeredNavigation` folder from `/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma` to my theme path `app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/` and ran the static content deploy.

I then receive the following error message:

> main.CRITICAL: variable @filter-quantity is undefined in file magento-install/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/frontend/vendor/theme/en_GB/Magento_LayeredNavigation/css/source/_module.less in _module.less on line 105, column 29
>   103| 
>   104|         &-value {
>   105|             .lib-css(color, @filter-quantity);
>   106|         }
>   107| 
>   108|         &-options { {"exception":"[object] (Magento\Framework\View\Asset\ContentProcessorException(code: 0): variable @filter-quantity is undefined in file magento-install/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/frontend/vendor/theme/en_GB/Magento_LayeredNavigation/css/source/_module.less in _module.less on line 105, column 29
>   103| 
>   104|         &-value {
>   105|             .lib-css(color, @filter-quantity);
>   106|         }
>   107| 
>   108|         &-options { at magento-install/vendor/magento/framework/Css/PreProcessor/Adapter/Less/Processor.php:97)"} []

Answer (score 1):

I created a _extend.less and copied the relevant css from luma theme into it that was needed from the following files.

`/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Catalog/web/css/source/module/_toolbar.less`

> @toolbar-background: transparent;

`/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_module.less`

> @filter-title-background-color: @color-gray94;
>
> @filter-link: @color-gray-darken4;
>
> @filter-link-hover: darken(@filter-link, 30%);
>
> @filter-quantity: @color-gray46;

Inserted the _extend.less into `app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/web/css/source` and ran the static content deploy.