# Using luma LayeredNavigation in custom theme based on blank theme

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, luma-theme, custom-theme, blank-theme

I want to copy the style and functionality of luma layered navigation to my custom theme - parent is blank theme.
If I copy the Magento_LayeredNavigation of luma theme to my custom theme `<vendor>/<theme>/Magento_LayeredNavigation`

then it re-styles everything.

[image]

I think I need to copy some additional files/modules to my custom theme?! Maybe I just need some CSS which I need to append to my _extend.less files?!

Can you give detailed instructions how to solve this problem?
Thank you!

Comment: This answer works! https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/301096/how-to-copy-luma-layered-navigation-to-blank-theme

Answer (score 0):

U should make a child theme of luma to achieve this rather making a different custom theme. Here is a reference link on how to create a child theme.
https://www.google.com/amp/s/meetanshi.com/blog/create-child-theme-in-magento-2/amp/

Comment: We have more abilities to customize with blank theme. Thank you!

Comment: In that case, there is only one way to do it. Copy directory `/vendor/magento/module-layered-navigation/view/` in to `/app/design/frontend/Vendor/YourTheme/Magento_LayeredNavigation/`

Comment: This does not work! I saw your answer in a other question. The reason ist, that the relevant css is not included!